# Adding Counter to Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, counter, correlated-subquery, cumulative-sum

I have a correlated subquery in Access that gets running totals of a rating for each person being evaluated. I would like to know how I can insert a counter to keep track of how many records are added into the running total so I can use it to calculate an average rating for each person by taking the running total / the count. This is probably pretty simple to a more experienced person, but I haven't managed to get it working and could use any assistance available to speed me along in the process. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT FieldEval1.EvaluateeID, FieldEval1.EvalDate, FieldEval1.EvalSkillVal, FieldEval1.EvalSkillVal, 
  (SELECT Sum(FieldEval2.EvalSkillVal) 
   FROM FieldEvaluations AS FieldEval2 
   WHERE FieldEval2.EvaluateeID = FieldEval1.EvaluateeID AND FieldEval2.EvalDate <= FieldEval1.EvalDate) AS SkillTotal
FROM FieldEvaluations AS FieldEval1;
```

What I have so far is working to create the running totals for each person.

Comment: Please check syntax first, comma is missing before subquery.

Comment: I want to be able to set parameters for which records are counted. The people who did the evaluations were allowed (by my boss) to either enter 1-5 or leave blank - a value of zero indicates they left it blank. If the value added to the running total is zero, it means that an evaluation wasn't done for a person so I wouldn't want to count that record in calculating an average. Maybe I could somehow specify the parameters of the subquery Avg(EvalSkillVal) to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have to pick this up again in the morning since my office closed and kicked me out. I feel like the answer is very near and will update tomorrow. 

Comment: @HansUp - This is the code I came up with after your assistance brainstorming (it seems to be working).  SELECT FieldEval1.EvaluateeID, FieldEval1.EvalDate, FieldEval1.EvalSkillVal, (SELECT Avg(FieldEval2.EvalSkillVal) FROM FieldEvaluations AS FieldEval2 WHERE ((FieldEval2.EvalSkillVal)>0) AND FieldEval2.EvaluateeID = FieldEval1.EvaluateeID AND FieldEval2.EvalDate <= FieldEval1.EvalDate) AS SkillAvg
FROM FieldEvaluations AS FieldEval1
WHERE (((FieldEval1.EvalSkillVal)>0));

Comment: I am not sure how to post sample data, but if you are interested I can try to figure that out so you can see the original data compared to the results.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving some assistance from others in clarifying my problem and what results I needed to obtain, I came up with the following code:

```
SELECT FieldEval1.EvaluateeID, FieldEval1.EvalDate, FieldEval1.EvalSkillVal, 
  (SELECT Avg(FieldEval2.EvalSkillVal) 
   FROM FieldEvaluations AS FieldEval2 
   WHERE ((FieldEval2.EvalSkillVal)>0) AND FieldEval2.EvaluateeID = FieldEval1.EvaluateeID AND FieldEval2.EvalDate <= FieldEval1.EvalDate) AS SkillAvg 
FROM FieldEvaluations AS FieldEval1 
WHERE (((FieldEval1.EvalSkillVal)>0));
```

This code will give me average ratings for each person while ignoring records where a value of zero exists (zero indicates that no rating was performed on that person in that category).

Answer (score 0):

I don't write my SQL with subqueries as columns.  It's usually clearer (and IIRC, standard) to use a join instead.  [Here's an example](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#running.totals) with an explanation.

Once you have the less-than comparison and GROUP BY right using that form, running totals start to look pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. I am going to study it for awhile because right now it seems intimidating; hoping it makes more sense after I spend more time looking over it.